# deploy a sinatra app with passenger gives only 404, page not founds. Yet a simple rack app works

Tags: ruby, sinatra, passenger, deployment, rack

I have correctly (or prbably not) installed passenger on apache 2. Rack works, but sinatra keeps giving 404's.

**Here is what works:**
*config.ru*:

```
#app = proc do |env|
  return [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, "hello <b>world</b>"]  
end
run app
```

**Here is what works too:**
Running the app.rb (see below) with *ruby app.rb* and then looking at localhost:4567/about and /

restarting the app, gives me a correct hello world. w00t.

**But then there is the sinatra entering the building:**
*config.ru*

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :root,        root_dir
set :app_file,    File.join(root_dir, 'app.rb')
disable :run

run Sinatra::Application
```

and an *app.rb*

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do 
 "Hallo wereld!"
end

get '/about' do
 "Hello world, it's #{Time.now} at the server!"
end
```

This keeps giving 404s. 
*/var/logs/apache2/error.log* lists these correctly as "404" with something that worries me:

```
83.XXXXXXXXX - - [30/May/2010 16:06:52] "GET /about " 404 18 0.0007
83.XXXXXXXXX - - [30/May/2010 16:06:56] "GET / " 404 18 0.0007
```

The thing that worried me, is the space after the / and the /about. Would apache or sinatra go looking for /[space], like /%20?

If anyone knows what this problem relates to, maybe a known bug (that I could not find) or a known gotcha? 
Maybe I am just being stupid and getting "it all wrong?"

Otherwise any hints on where to get, read or log more developers data on a running rack, sinatra or passenger app would be helpfull too: to see what sinatra is looking for, for example.

Some other information:
Running ubuntu 9.04, apache2-mm-prefork (deb), mod_php5, ruby 1.8.7, passenger 2.2.11, sinatra 1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not loading the routes in app.rb. To do this, replace `require 'sinatra'` with `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app.rb')` in config.ru.

```
root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
app_file = File.join(root_dir, 'app.rb')
require app_file

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :root,        root_dir
set :app_file,    app_file
disable :run

run Sinatra::Application
```

`set :app_file` won't load them for you.

Comment: Thanks a million. I will try to get this fixed in the passenger documentation too. http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_sinatra

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the `require sinatra` with a `require 'app'` and you're set to go.